# Javascript toggle paging on all dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm struggling to make a js function that will toggle paging on all the dataTables on my page.  What am I doing wrong?

Note: whenever I run `togglePaging()` in the Chrome console, I get `undefined` as a response.

```
var globalPaging = true;

function togglePaging() {

    globalPaging = !globalPaging;

    $('.dataTable').each(function(){

        var oTable = $(this).dataTable();        
        var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
        oSettings.aoColumns[1].bPaginate = globalPaging;

        var oTableDT = $(this).DataTable();
        oTableDT.draw(); 

    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table.toDataTable').DataTable({ 
        "bPaginate": globalPaging    
    });
});
```

Here's a demo:
[jsfiddle.net/8n1nj0bu](https://jsfiddle.net/8n1nj0bu/)

---

**Update:** Here is the solution I went with, derived from Teddy's answer: [jsfiddle.net/jyf8h2je](https://jsfiddle.net/jyf8h2je/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The draw() function update your table content only. If you want change other property, maybe you need re-init your table.
Draw API: https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw

My example:

```
$('.dataTable').each(function(){
    var oTableDT = $(this).DataTable({ 
        "bPaginate": globalPaging,
        "bDestroy": true
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8n1nj0bu/1/

This solution has an disadvantage that is you need re-init all your properties.

Note: My FF43 cant run onclick, so I use jquery instead.

Comment: So, I assume it's possible to save state, do the destroy, then reapply state in order to prevent the toggling of paging from discarding the applied searched filter. Right? (If it's easy, could you show how to do this please?)

Comment: ...actually, perhaps I should just use `search()` to get the search terms, then do the destroy/paging-toggle, then use the search terms in a `search(<terms>)` call, followed by `draw()`.

Comment: @synaptik If you want search, it's only change content of table, so draw() should work well.

Comment: thanks. I just posted my solution (which is just yours with slight modifications).  It retains the search filter.